# Why do I get a negative output when I run my program to compute the sum of all even Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, fibonacci

**Background:**

I'm working on Project Euler problem #2 and I have a class built to solve the problem.  For those who haven't done this before, this is the problem:

*Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ... .
By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.*

**The problem:**

I have the program built to solve the problem given, but when I run it, I get the value **-1833689714**.  This should not be the value returned, as I sum only positive numbers and no multiplications are performed that I know of.  How do I fix this?

**My code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int answer = resultsSum(fibonacci(4000000));
    System.out.println(answer);

  }

  public static int resultsSum(ArrayList<Integer> resultList){

    int total = 0;
    for(Integer r : resultList){

      total += r.intValue();

    }

    return total;

  }

  public static ArrayList<Integer> fibonacci(int n){

    ArrayList fibEvens = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    fibEvens.add(b);

    for(int i = 1; i < (n - 1); i++) {

      int tempVar = a;
      a = b;
      b += tempVar;
      if(b % 2 == 0){

        fibEvens.add(b);

      }
    }
    return fibEvens;
  }
}
```

https://projecteuler.net/problem=2

Comment: You are experiencing an interview overflow. As one answered says you are going to the 4000000th Fibonacci value rather than ensuring your Fibonacci code doesn't exceed 4 million. Look up the first 100 values of the sequence. You should stop after the 33rd value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting a negative result is that the the terms of the Fibonacci sequence above the 88th term are in excess of the maximum positive value of the `Long` data type in java, which is 9,223,372,036,854,775,80.

When you attempt to increment the long data type beyond it's max value by one it wraps around to the minimum value (-9,223,372,036,854,775,80). At the point the Fibonacci terms exceed the max value, you're doing this many times over.

Additionally, the problem you've posted indicates that you should be stopping when the value of the number derived from the sequence is greater than 4 million, not trying to add the even values of the first 4 million values (which is huge).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your code is attempting to get to the 4-millionth Fibonacci number, which is quite different than *the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million*.

Answer (score 1):

Because

- `int` data type stores number from `-2^31` to `2^31 - 1`
- `Integer` data type stores number from `-2^63` to `2^63 - 1`

Try with [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

```
public static BigInteger fibonacci(int n) {
    BigInteger[] f = new BigInteger[n + 1];
    f[0] = BigInteger.ZERO;
    if (n > 0) {
        f[1] = BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < f.length; i++) {
        f[i] = f[i - 1].add(f[i - 2]);
    }
    return f[n];
}
```

But the 4 million Fibonacci value very long. See more [300th](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html), [500th](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable301.html)